# SQL Multiple where on same field

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
FieldA | FieldB
---------------
1        12
1        13
1        14
2        12
2        13
3        12
3        13
```

I want to obtain FieldA, where FieldB is equal to 12, but also equal to 13, but NOT equal to 14.

```
Expected output:

FieldA
-------
2
3
```

So far I've come to this:

```
SELECT FieldA FROM table
WHERE FieldB IN (12, 13) AND FieldB NOT IN (14)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, what am I missing ? Also, I would like to do it in a way that it is cross-database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subqueries.  I like to handle these with `group by` and `having`, because this is a very flexible approach.  Based on the question in the text:

```
SELECT FieldA
FROM table
GROUP BY FieldA
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is checking for one of the conditions you care about.  The first counts the number of rows where `FieldB = 12` and the `> 0` makes sure there is at least one.  The second counts the number of rows where `FieldB = 14`.  The `= 0` makes sure there are none.

If, as suggested by your code, you want 12 *and* 13, then you can do:

```
SELECT FieldA
FROM table
GROUP BY FieldA
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

And, if you want 12 *or* 13, you can do:

```
SELECT FieldA
FROM table
GROUP BY FieldA
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB IN (12, 13) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldB = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Will it also work on multiple databases ? (For instance even Sqlite ?)

Comment: @Kei . . . Yes.  This is all standard SQL and should work on the current versions of all real databases (oops, my bias access MS Access is showing).  (I mean, assuming you don't really have a table named `table`.)

Comment: I wasn't doubting; since I edited the question and added the "cross-database" part at the end, I thought you posted before I did that.